# Issue with Laravel extends

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, extends

I am doing a project in laravel and `extends` doesn't work properly. On my home page i extends layout but when i try to extend layout on other pages it fails and i do same things on both pages.

**This is my home page where extends works properly**

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('body')
<center><a href="todo/create" class="btn btn-info">Add New</a></center>
    <a href="todo/ce" class="btn btn-info">ce</a>
<table class="table-condensed">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Body</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>asdasd</td>
            <td>asdasd</td>
            <td>asdasda</td>
            <td> <a href="">Edit</a></td>
            <td> <a href="">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
@endsection
```

**And here is my create page where extends doesn't work**

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('body')
<p>Ovo je create page</p>
@endsections
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: opens blank page.on inspect element thers no error

Comment: Where is your `main_layout.blade.php` file located? Is it in any sub-folder? For example, `front/abc/main_layout.blade.php`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@endsections` to `@endsection`. You can fill your `@section` using `@yield('body')`.

Eg.

`main_layout.blade.php`

```
<html>
    <header>
        <title>@yield('title', 'Hello')</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        @yield('body')
    </body>
</html>
```

And yours body in file like `my_body.blade.php`

```
@extends('main_layout')

@section('title', 'My page')

@section('body')
    <p>Hello world!</p>
@endsection
```

Now your title can be filled by `"My page"` and  by the parapgraph "Hello world!".

Comment: Are u sure, your controller render correct view? `return view('pages.my_page')`

Comment: i check all guys,everything looks good.i extended on home page the same way and it works.its really confusing

Comment: if someone knows whats the problem please help me.its really imortant to me to fix this soon